# Is it possible to re-share folders from a shared drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, nas

We have a Windows server with shares used by legacy software. We also have a NAS.

Ideally we would just map a network drive to the NAS and then replace the current shares with new shares of the same name.  It would give us time to refactor the legacy software without running out of disk space.

However, we can't seem to share anything from the mounted shared drive (and I'm not very familiar with Windows).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using standard windows commands. Junctions won't help either.

A possibility would be to mount the share in Linux using samba, then to share it from there (maybe using samba or NFS).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating systems and applications involved, symbolic links might work.  That is, keep the existing shares on the Windows server but replace the content with symbolic links to the content on the NAS.  Note that the clients will be connecting to the NAS, not the server, so this is only an option if the clients can already authenticate.

You can create symbolic links with the mklink commands.